# Find which array element exists in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

Is there any method or quick way to see which of the elements in an array exists in a string?

```
const myArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
const myString = 'somelongbarstring';
```

In this example, `bar` from the array exists in `myString`, so I need to get `bar` given `myArray` and `myString`.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `find` with `includes`:

```js
const myArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
const myString = 'somelongbarstring';

const res = myArray.find(e => myString.includes(e));

console.log(res);
```

If you want to find all items included in the string, swap out `find` for `filter`:

```js
const myArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
const myString = 'somelongbarstring-baz';

const res = myArray.filter(e => myString.includes(e));

console.log(res);
```

If you want the index, use `findIndex`:

```js
const myArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
const myString = 'somelongbarstring';

const res = myArray.findIndex(e => myString.includes(e));

console.log(res);
```

Multiple indexes is a little tricky - you'd have to use the [`Array.prototype.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) method to preserve the original indexes because `filter` returns a new array with new indexes:

```js
const myArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
const myString = 'somelongbarstring-baz';

const res = [...myArray.keys()].filter((e, i, a) => myString.includes(myArray[e]));

console.log(res);
```

<sub>(You could also swap out `e` for `i` in the above function, but it's more understandable to do this because we're iterating through the keys.)</sub>

Comment: Or `.filter` for all

Comment: Edited (a lot) @JonasWilms.

Comment: @JackBashford Your last example doesn't work?

Comment: Fixed @Kobe - also thanks for the indices!

Comment: No worries, indexes sounds better but English is weird :P

Comment: Indices is more mathematics-related.

Comment: @JackBashford in fact, you're correct. Indexes is actually the better plural to go for here, I never knew that was the rule. Index when pertaining to an indicator is perfectly fine as per [this](https://writingexplained.org/indexes-or-indices-difference). I never even knew indexes was a thing. You learn something new every day.

Comment: No worries, I'll re-edit - thanks for fixing it anyway, I always appreciate people making me look smarter/less likely to have a trashy keyboard.